# CSS last entries not loading when runserver (Django)?

Tags: html, css, django

The problem should be fairly simple.

I have 2 HTML files styled by a unique CSS. Basically I have written CSS code for one HTML (the home page) yesterday, and everything works fine. Today I am adding a few 'div' and 'class' elements to the second HTML (checkout) but the code I have added to the CSS today seems to have no effect (code from yesterday works fine though).

So, I have inspected the page run on localhost and loaded the link to the CSS. Well, I have found out that the code I have written today is not being loaded.

Obviously I have saved the CSS, and also tried to close PyCharm and restart the project, but it does not seem to work.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my project directories tree:

[image]

The CSS

```
body {
background-color: green;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: Sans-serif;
}
h3 {
font-size: 90%;
}
.menu{
background-color: CadetBlue;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
margin:auto;
}
.order {
background-color: Brown;
float: right;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
.restaurant_name {
color: yellow;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
padding-top:5%;
}
.order_header {
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10%;
background: grey;
color: yellow;
border-left: 4px solid LightSeaGreen;
}
.menu_and_order {
padding: 5%;
}
.menu_title {
background: grey;
color: yellow;
border-left: 4px solid LightSeaGreen;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 2.5em;
}
td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: auto;
}
.checkout {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 3px;
margin-left: 10%;
background-color: CadetBlue;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin: 10%;
background-color: grey;
}
.link {
margin-left: 35%;
}
.order_table {
width: 100%;
}
th {
padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.page_title {
color: yellow;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
padding-top:5%
}
.order_summary {
background-color: Brown;
margin: auto;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.customer_details {
float: right;
}
```

N.B. from `.page_title` the code is not being loaded on localhost

The second (checkout HTML) is the following.

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Checkout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/my_cart.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="order_summary">
    <h1 class="page_title">Order summary</h1>
    <h3>The following items will be ready to be collected:</h3>
    <h3>Reference number: {{ cart }}</h3>
    <table class="order_table">
        {% for cart_item in cart_items %}
        <tr class="order_item">
            <td>{{ cart_item.item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
<form class="customer_details" action="{% url 'successful_order' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Order">
</form>
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Back to order</a></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Probably that's all you need, but here is also the code I have added to `settings.py`

Should you need me to provide other code, just let me know.

Thank you for any reply

Comment: CSS is cached by the browser, have tried ctrl+f5?

Comment: It worked! Thank you but I am just learning Django and I have never encountered this.

Comment: have  you run commands like collectstatic and performed migrations?

Comment: I was checking 'collectstatics' on the documentation but it seems to involve the static root settings, which I haven't specified in settings.py. Migrations are to be run only when making changes to the models as far as I know. Running ctrl+f5 worked fine, but should I also run migrations in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers cache the CSS to allow faster page loading for repeat visitors.

Using ctrl+f5 in the browser whenever you make any changes to the CSS forces it to update the cache.

Firefox and Chrome both have an option in the dev tools to disable the cache when the tools are open.